# BGInfo Script to change date format to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: vbscript, background, format, desktop

I use this code to change the date format for BGInfo but I get error code on line 3

Mismatch error 'Format" 800A000D

```
Dim dt, strDate
dt = Date
strDate = Format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd")
BGInfo.BGI.Date = strDate
```

Research I've done doesn't seen to find a solution

I've tried this:

```
 Dim strDate As String
 strDate = Format(Now(), "yyyy/mm/dd")
 BGInfo.BGI.Date = strDate
```

but that didn't work

Comment: BGInfo works with VBScript, not VBA. Format is a VBA function.

Comment: @user692942 That link won't really help if the OP wants to change bginfo's built-in fields, such as "Boot Time", which is probably the case since the OP tried to change the format of a non-existing "bginfo.bgi" object.

Comment: Yeah, that’s another issue along with the fact it’s VBScript not VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BGInfo uses VBScript in it's **Custom** field **VB Script file** option. It does not support VBA, so VBA functions, such as **Format** cannot be used.

The Following code can be placed in the **Custom** field to provide a new field, that can be placed on screen, to display the date in yyyy-mm-dd format:

```
Echo Year(Now()) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(Now()),2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(Now()),2)
```

However, this will not change the format of the existing fields, such as **Boot Time**.

There is no **bginfo** object, so the code `BGInfo.BGI.Date = strDate` will not work. The only way to change the date format for bginfo's built-in fields is to change the user's date format.

You can work around the issue by temporarily changing the user's date format to yyyy-mm-dd, running bginfo, and then change the date format back. Here's the code (save this to a separate file, such as **RunBGInfo.vbs**):

```
Set oWSH = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sDateReg = "HKCU\Control Panel\International\sShortDate"
UserDateFormat = oWSH.RegRead(sDateReg)
oWSH.RegWrite(sDateReg),"yyyy-MM-dd"
oWSH.Run "bginfo.exe bginfo.bgi /timer:0 ",1,True
oWSH.RegWrite(sDateReg),UserDateFormat
```

You may also want to look at a bginfo alternative written in PowerShell (such as [this one](https://github.com/zincarla/BGPSInfo)) that you can then modify and extend to meet your requirements.